# How do I get a list of Dynamic Distribution Groups in Office 365?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

In Office 365 Exchange how does one obtain a list of existing dynamic distribution groups?  Is power shell required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your groups via web UI:
Exchange admin center -> recipients -> groups
Then you need to search -> advanced search
provide recipient types "Dynamic distribution groups" and OK it

[image]

Powershell is not required, but is a good option:
You need to connect to Exchange Online session as per [Microsoft Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Supply your Office365 admin user credentials:
`$UserCredential = Get-Credential`

Then create a session(one line):
`$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`

And finally `Import-PSSession $Session`

When connected issue `Get-DynamicDistributionGroup` which will give you the list.

Comment: Using powershell, I'm able to get a list using `Get-DistributionGroup` but not using `Get-DynamicDistributionGroup`, as that command does not exist when I try to use it.

Comment: Make sure there is no error when you connect to office 365 session. I think you might miss some cmdlets if you have PowerShell execution policy set too restricted.

Comment: I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy ByPass` and then tried your powershell suggestion again, but I still don't end up with the `Get-DynamicDistributionGroup` I do however have a `Set-DynamicDistributionGroup`, I don't really want to use it though.  I also received something about setting an `AllowClobber` parameter when importing them, and then a bunch of commands that I assume are local and that importing them would use a proxy to call it remotely instead of the local ones.

Comment: Is it possible that the `Get-DynamicDistributionGroup` has been deprecated by `Get-DistributionGroup`?

Comment: Okay, it seems you already have Exchange powershell module on the machine where you run this session. AllowClobber would allow to merge modules, if I'm not mistaken. I would suggest you follow the article's section "What do you need to know before you begin?" to avoid any confusion. Dynamic Distribution Groups wouldn't deprecate regular DGs.

Comment: we used to have exchange on-premise, so I bet that is the case...wonder if there's a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exchange admin center to view all available dynamic distribution group. else you can use below PowerShell commands.

```
$Credential=Get-Credential -Credential $null 
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection  
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber
Get-DynamicDistributionGroup
```

viewing members of a Dynamic Distribution Group are not feasible in the Office 365 Admin Portal.PowerShell is the only way to view members.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-Dynamic-7f66e229